# pioneer3-at I dont wnt to use ssh to remotely control robot

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ssh, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"pioneer3-at I dont wnt to use ssh to remotely control robot"

Hi everyone, I have a problem like this:

Every time I want to operate my Pioneer 3at robot, I need to use "ssh" command to access the on board computer on a remote laptop. And then I can run "RosAria" to connect the robot (**rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyS0**). If I want to control the robot to move, I already know how to control it remotely by running another program that publishes "vel_cmd" [by setting ROS_MASTER_URI].

so, the question is: I don't want to control the robot by the method above, it is not convenient to access onboard computer or set ROS_MASTER_URI etc. I want to remotely run **rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyS0** and control the robot. but it doesn't work, since the hardware is connected to onboard computer by serial port directly.
Actually, I plan to control multiple robots (e.g.,5), If I use "ssh"..., I will at least open 5 terminals, that will cost much time and is not convenient.

Thus, is anyone know how to solve this problem? just open one terminal, and run RosAria on remote laptop and can connect to and control the robots...

Or do you think this cannot be realized?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145351/pioneer3-at-i-dont-wnt-to-use-ssh-to-remotely-control-robot/) by [Fei_Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13936/fei_liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few ways you can solve this:

- Use a roslaunch file to do remote launches on all of your robots. With this method, you would have a roslaunch file that you run locally, which will automatically ssh to all robots and run the rosaria driver. Take a look at the [roslaunch machine tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine) and the [machine argument](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes) to the node tag. You'll need to set up ssh keys for passwordless login to all of your robots.
- Set up the rosaria node and a ROS master to run at startup on each robot. This works well for a singe robot, but won't work well if you want all robots to connect to the same ROS master.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fei_Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/13936/fei_liu/) on 2014-03-27**:
thanks for your suggestion. I will try that and post the result later.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-03-27**:
RosAria works like a charm, I'm using it on my telepresence robot. At least with a Pioneer 3-DX it does. Don't know about the AT, though.